# how to merge two wordpressplugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

```
i tried to combine both plugin its working sucessfully.

<?php /* Plugin Name: My Plugin Author: Dharmendra Chauhan Author URI: http://abhi4u.comlu.com Description: Combination of all plugins
*/

include dirname(__FILE__) . '\clicface-trombi\clicface-trombi.php'; 
include dirname(__FILE__) . '\Akismet\Akismet.php'; 
include dirname(__FILE__) . '\hrm\hrm.php';
include dirname(__FILE__) . '\piklist\piklist.php' ?>
```

i have two plugins 1.hrm, 2.wp-finance...so how to merge both of this
   plugin in to one...

```
..
```

Comment: You mean to call them together right?

Comment: If you are actually trying to merge the code of two different plugins... good luck. I would choose another approach.

Comment: yes i want to call together...

Comment: Masiorama...can you tell me is there any other method, so i can merge..